# AngularJs - "accesskey" only active when associated control is visible

Tags: angularjs

I have a `div` with a button

```
<div ng-hide="edittingCampaign">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" ng-click="AddCampaign();" 
           accesskey='a'>Add a new campaign</button>
</div>
```

Even when that div and the button are visible, the shortcut key can be used.

Is there anyway to prevent that with a directive?

Or do I have to edit the handler function?

```
$scope.AddCampaign = function ()
{    
    // add this check ...
    if ($scope.edittingCampaign)
         return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead:

> `ngIf` differs from `ngShow` and `ngHide` in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property.

Comment: I suppose there is very, very, slight run-time hit when removing & adding the element, but for a button it will be negligible.  Are there any gotchas with ng-if ?